# Increment and Decrement a quantity within a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem. If I click on an increase button, the item quantity also increases. When I click on the decrement button, I get the same result. Here is where I declare the `ArrayList<>`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

public static Context c;
int quantity=0;
public static int qty,cty,mty=0,qty1;
public static int sendcost;
public static String curry;
MyHolder holder;

public ArrayList<Integer> quantity1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<>();
CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

private boolean mShowQuantity;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts, boolean showQuantity ) {//ArrayList<ShoppingCartEntry> showQuantity   ,  boolean showQuantity
    MyAdapter.c = c;
    this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    this.mShowQuantity = showQuantity;

    for(int i =0; i< spacecrafts.size();i++ )
    {
        quantity1.add(0);
        //quantity[i]=0;
    }

}
```

This is where I organise the `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);


    return new MyHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Spacecraft s = spacecrafts.get(position);



    holder.nameTxt.setText(s.getName());
    PicassoClient.downloadImage(c, s.getImageUrl(), holder.img);
    holder.propellentTxt.setText(s.getPropellant());
    holder.descTxt.setText(s.getDescription());
    holder.carbohydratesTxt.setText(s.getCarbohydrates());
    holder.fatcontentTxt.setText(s.getFatcontent());
    holder.minaralsTxt.setText(s.getMinarals());
    holder.costTxt.setText("" + s.getCost());
    holder.rateTxt.getText().toString();

    try{

        holder.rateTxt.setText(quantity1.get(position)+"");


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    MyHolder.btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            quantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.rateTxt.getText().toString());

            cty = Integer.parseInt(holder.costTxt.getText().toString());

            curry =holder.nameTxt.getText().toString();

             qty1 = 1;

            quantity = quantity + 1;


            holder.rateTxt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));//quantity

            sendcost = quantity * cty;//single item cost


            mty = mty + cty * qty1;// Total Cost




            MainActivity.Totalcost.setText("Total cost :" + String.valueOf(mty));

            ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(s, quantity);


        }
    });
```

Here is my decrease button:

```
    MyHolder.btn_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {

            qty1=1;
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.rateTxt.getText().toString());
            cty = Integer.parseInt(holder.costTxt.getText().toString());
            if(quantity == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                quantity = quantity - 1;

                holder.rateTxt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

                mty =mty - cty*qty1;



                MainActivity.Totalcost.setText("Total cost :" + String.valueOf(mty));



                ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(s, quantity);


            }




        }



    });

    holder.quan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return spacecrafts.size();
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make the decrease button work?

Comment: You need to update your arraylist each time when you increase and decrease the quantity. And after updating the list call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thank you sir. please add some code because i am new to android....

Comment: quantity1.set(position, quantity);  notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: it works. some time it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the comments, they are all accurate. You need to update the `ArrayList<>` each time you increase and decrease the quantities. After you do that, you need to notify your `RecyclerView`s adapter like so:

```
quantity1.set(position, quantity);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When you update the `ArrayList<>`, any new changes that were made would appear in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong in the code that you'll have to figure out.